# Designing the class inheritance of my custom control

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, custom-controls, class-design

I am creating a couple different custom controls, each of which implement different base controls, but they all will be getting some common properties and functionality added to them.  So I was wanting to place those common properties (with their common getters and setters) and the duplication of the functionality into an abstract class.  But I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to architect the controls and its bases to allow the implementation of both my abstract class and the base web control I'm building on top of.  Can anyone help me out?

**Some of the controls I'm building**

```
public class AssetDataStringControl : TextBox
public class AssetDataIntegerControl : TextBox
public class AssetDataUrlControl : CompositeControl
public class AssetDataListBoxControl : ListBox
public class AssetDataDropDownControl : DropDownList
```

**My abstract class**

```
public abstract class AssetDataInputControlBase<T> : Control, 
    IAssetDataInputControl<T>
{
    protected virtual int AssetId
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["AssetId"];
            return o == null ? 0 : (int)o;
        }
        set { ViewState["AssetId"] = value; }
    }

    protected virtual AssetStructureField StructureField
    {
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["StructureField"];
            return o == null ? null : (AssetStructureField)o;
        }
        set { ViewState["StructureField"] = value; }
    }

    public abstract T DataField { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about `abstract`. Seems to me that the .NET web control inheritance chain layers on functionality rather than forcing tons of implementation on the poor "end product" controls. I'd see if I can go with the flow on this. And this implies inheriting from the appropriate class to get the base upon which to build (pun intended).

Looks like you want to build composite web controls.  **Read carefully** the documentation on `System.Web.UI` namespace. Consider inheriting from `System.Web.UI.CompositeControl`. It gives you a child control collection and some built-in rendering. And it implements `INamingContainer` for managing child control unique IDs.

Just a thought, maybe you can make a class that constructs custom composites at runtime (can you say `factory pattern`?).  **Read carefully** the documentation on `System.Web.UI` namespace Anyway, the base already knows how to render the composite. Each sub-control (textbox, listbox, etc) knows how to render itself. In the factory, each sub-control is given it's data binding. Then injects them into your custom CompositeControl constructor(s).

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion:  make AssetDataInputControlBase a Canvas and place any Control you want inside it.  Being a canvas, it will behave a lot like a control.  Any Control specific methods/properties you need would necessitate adding methods to ADICB that call the Control methods.  If there's a lot of them, this idea isn't so good.

Another suggestion:  Your controls could implement an interface that has a method that returns something like AssetDataInputControlBase, only in this case ADICB would not implement Control, or anything else.  Instead, it would just have AssetID, AssetStructureField, and DataField (and other stuff as needed later).  So your controls (such as AssetDataStringControl) just extend a Control (such as TextBox) and, in addition, contain a reference to to an ADICB object.

This assumes the ADICB's values are rather independent of the Control (TextBox, say).  If StructureField's get method needs all kinds of information from the TextBox, and needs to get it in different ways is if is instead a ListBox, everything's going to get all tangled up and you need a better solution.  If *not*, your controls are just extentions of TextBox, ListBox, etc., with one added reference to an ADICB object.  One ADICB class, however complex, once written can be used by all your controls.

This does look like a good argument for multiple inheritance.